# AllShortestPaths missing relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been using all shortest paths to retrieve all relationships within a certain number of relations from a root node. As an example, the following queries are run against the standard Matrix themed [graph](http://console.neo4j.org/).

Query 1:

```
MATCH p = allshortestPaths((n:Crew)-[r*0..3]-(m))
WHERE n.name = 'Neo' UNWIND relationships(p) AS rels
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT rels)
```

Query 2:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)-[r*0..3]-(m)
WHERE n.name = 'Neo' UNWIND r AS rels
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT rels)
```

The second example works as intended but the allShortestPaths example misses the relationship between Morpheus and Trinity.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `allShortestPaths()` example omits the relationship between `Morpheus` and `Trinity` because the shortest path between `Neo` and `Trinity` does not include the omitted relationship.

The `allShortestPaths()` example is returning the shortest path between `Neo` and every *distinct* node that is at most 3 steps away. Since there is already a direct 1-step path between `Neo` and `Trinity`, any longer paths between those 2 nodes are ignored.